# How to create a view mixin that implements common child view

Tags: ember.js

Is there an example of a mixin that implements a child view that are common to several view of an application. For example, I like to add a toolbar to every part of my application and to avoid to duplicate the toolbar element in my views template, I'd like to use mixins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the layout property on Ember.View. You can have a shared layout template across the views.

http://docs.emberjs.com/#doc=Ember.View&src=false

You could also potentially achieve something like this using Ember.ContainerView. Your classes could add views to the childViews array.

http://docs.emberjs.com/#doc=Ember.ContainerView&src=false